# Order posts alphabetically with numbers but some of the posts has numbers in the title

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, order

I have this query:

```
 $args = array(  

    'post_type' => 'alerts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'post_title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$alerts_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The problem is that the order breaks in certain point. look at the imagen any ideas why it breaks. I have used:

```
'orderby' => 'title',
'suppress_filters' => true,
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
```

[image]

Comment: Sorting by post titles sorts them alphabetically, not numerically. 6 comes after 59 because 6 is a later 'letter' than 5. If you want to sort these numerically, the number will need to be a custom field, which you can sort by separately.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jacob, I can see you are totally right, you say that once I create a alert I have to type a number in a custom field and then use a meta_query to sort it? is there a way to create the number automatically? thanks a lot